# getting model view matrix in Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es

how to get current model view matrix in Android?i am using OpenGL 1.1,the method GL.getFloatv() is giving zero values.please help.

```
float[] model_matrix = new float[16];
GL11.getFloatv(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,model_matrix);
```

Comment: Exactly how are you calling it?

Comment: i am calling them like this Andreas  float[] maodel_matrix = new float[16];   GL11.getFloatv(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,model_matrix);  please let me know if u have idea..

Comment: Maybe you have the same problem as in this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125557/problem-with-getfloatv-function-in-gl11-android

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, since you don't show any code: you should be using GL11.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, and not GL_MODELVIEW for requesting the matrix values.

Comment: float[] maodel_matrix = new float[16]; GL11.getFloatv(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,model_matrix);i tried this.after executing this method also,model_matrix is giving zero values..did you used this method earlier?if so please help me how you used it..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still pending or which version you used, but as of now, the GLES11.glGetFloatv has 2 overloads and the the one using float[16] requires 3 parameters. The one with 2 params takes a FloatBuffer.
This works for me:

```
float[] model_matrix = new float[16];
GLES11.glGetFloatv(GLES11.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, model_matrix, 0);
```