# Android glGetFloatv called unimplemented "OpenGL ES API"

Tags: android, opengl-es

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with getFloatv function in GL11 (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125557/problem-with-getfloatv-function-in-gl11-android)

When "**glGetFloatv**" is called in my draw method, I've found that the ModelMatrix is populated with zeros but I expected that the ModelMatrix is filled because the object is translated one unit in Z and Y axis.  Looking for what could be the reason for that, I've found that LogCat is throwing the next message: "**libEGL called unimplemented OpenGL ES API**".

I could guess that I haven't running the correct OpenGL version but I've forced taking the OpenGL ES 2 and the issue still happen.

My source code is below:

Render class

```
@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
        objectToDraw.Draw(gl);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {

    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);     
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);    
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f, 100.0f);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig egl) {

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL); 
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_ONE, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
}
```

Object Draw Method.

```
public void Draw(GL10 gl){
        gl11 = (GL11) gl;           
        gl11.glGetFloatv(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, _matrix,0);
            super.Draw();
        gl.glPopMatrix();
}
```

Finally, I'm not using Eclipse emulator, I'm debugging the application on HTC Wild Fire device (Emulator is too slow)

Comment: Finally, in the link that Tim has written, I've found this [link](http://www.41post.com/1540/programming/android-opengl-get-the-modelview-matrix-on-15-cupcake) where explains the reasons and how could be solved. Thanks Tim.