# How to get the projection and model view transforms in Android in java

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm trying to calculate a ray in my 3D world from a tap on an Android phone screen.
I thought I could just take the projection*modelview transform and inverse it. However, getting hold of the actual matrices doesn't seem to be so straightforward as I expected in OpenGL ES.

After a good while searching around the internet, options seem to be:

- Many people seem to be using a bunch of classes from an Android demo source [(MatrixGrabber, MatrixTrackingGL..)](http://magicscrollsofcode.blogspot.co.uk/2010/10/3d-picking-in-android.html).
- Use glGetFloatv. However this doesn't seem to exist in GL10. It seems to have been added in GL11 with [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125557/problem-with-getfloatv-function-in-gl11-android) [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106824/getting-model-view-matrix-in-android) and with [no documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/microedition/khronos/opengles/GL11.html#glGetFloatv(int,java.nio.FloatBuffer))).
- Implement your own matrix [code](http://code.google.com/p/rugl/source/browse/trunk/droid/DroidRUGL/src/com/ryanm/droid/rugl/gl/GLU.java).

Now it's almost two years since most of the stuff I've found was written and I find it hard to believe that google hasn't got around to make this easier for game developers on Android, so I'm assuming I'm just being blind. Is there an official or recommended way of doing this? Maybe something supported in the sdk?

Many thanks.